# How to use powershell to manage startup items of uwp app in windwos 10?

Tags: c#, powershell, uwp, startup

I hope to `enable/disable` the uwp app's startup items through powershell, but I tried to use `gcim win32_startupcommand` and `Get-Item HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run` and they couldn’t be found, `shell:startup` is also empty, it seems that uwp app is invisible and can only be seen in Task Manager->Startup, so what should I do?

I tried to use Regshot to compare the difference between before and after enabling the startup item, as follows:

[image: Regshot compare result]

In addition, I found that these registry entries did not exist before UWP or Task Manager was started, so in the end I thought this might be a very complicated solution, and I gave up doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a potential work-around until native calls to **[Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask]::RequestEnableSync()** and **::Disable()** methods are achieved...

In this example, I am toggling the state of Skype's desktop extension startup task:

```
$app = (Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object -Property Name -EQ -Value Microsoft.SkypeApp)
$pkgName = $app.PackageFamilyName
$startupTask = ($app | Get-AppxPackageManifest).Package.Applications.Application.Extensions.Extension | Where-Object -Property Category -Eq -Value windows.startupTask
$taskId = $startupTask.StartupTask.TaskId
$state = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\$pkgName\$taskId" -Name State).State
$regKey = "HKCU:Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\$pkgName\$taskId"
if ($state -in 0,1,3) {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name UserEnabledStartupOnce -Value 1
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name State -Value 2
} else {
    $lastDisabled = [int](New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT') -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name LastDisabledTime -Value $lastDisabled
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name State -Value 1
}
```

For more info about possible **State** values, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptaskstate?view=winrt-19041

For an example of how these tasks are built into UWP apps, see: https://windowsadmins.com/configure-your-app-to-start-at-log-in/

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this script is very useful. It can indeed toggle the status of the startup items. The only problem is that after I install the app, if I have not started the app or opened the task manager, the registry key will not exist and this The script won't work.

Comment: You can add a -Force flag to the Set-ItemProperty commands in the Powershell script above to create the Keys and Values if they do not already exist. An optional -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue will also make the script run cleaner, but that's an option that should be used with care. The first statement would therefore look like this Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name UserEnabledStartupOnce -Value 1 -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of where the skype app startup info is in the registry.  The registry key name seems to be non standard; maybe you can get the name of the key from the manifest or something.  Uwp apps are an inconvenience to admins.  Even Sysinternals Autoruns doesn't detect these.

```
$a = Get-AppxPackage *skype* | Get-AppPackageManifest
$a.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid
SkypeStartup

$a = get-appxpackage *windowsterminal* | Get-AppxPackageManifest
$a.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid
StartTerminalOnLoginTask


# list all the app startups
$starts = get-appxpackage -pv app | get-appxpackagemanifest | % {
if ($_.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid) {
  [pscustomobject] @{ PackageFamilyName = $app.PackageFamilyName
  TaskID = $_.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid} } }
$starts

PackageFamilyName                       TaskID
-----------------                       ------
Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c        SkypeStartup
AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa           {AppleMobileDeviceProcess, iTunesHelper}
Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe StartTerminalOnLoginTask


# so maybe to disable startups by setting them to 1:
$starts | % {
  $fname = $_.PackageFamilyName
  $_.taskid | % {
    $taskid = $_
    Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\$fname\$taskid" State 1 -whatif
  }
}

What if: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\SkypeStartup Property: State".
What if: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\AppleMobileDeviceProcess Property: State".
What if: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\iTunesHelper Property: State".
What if: Performing the operation "Set Property" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\StartTerminalOnLoginTask Property: State".
```

2 is enable, and 1 is disable.  Search for "Startup Apps" in the Settings app.

Skype:

HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\SkypeStartup\State=1(dword) (from procmon category is write)

Windows Terminal:

HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\StartTerminalOnLoginTask\State=1

iTunes has 2 startup tasks:

HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\AppleMobileDeviceProcess\State

HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\AppleInc.iTunes_nzyj5cx40ttqa\iTunesHelper\State

Maybe this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptask.disable?view=winrt-19041

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptask?view=winrt-19041

[Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask]

If someone tells me how to do it in C#, I can translate it to Powershell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have obtained similar results through comparison, but I finally think this solution is too complicated, because I found that after the UWP APP is installed, if the APP or task manager is not started, these registry keys Doesn't even exist, I gave up doing this, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To run commands (@***js2010***'s PowerShell script) in **Command Prompt** that disable the startup of any UWP app when login:

`powershell -c "$starts = get-appxpackage -pv app | get-appxpackagemanifest | % { if ($_.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid) {  [pscustomobject] @{ PackageFamilyName = $app.PackageFamilyName; TaskID = $_.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid} } }; $starts | % { $fname = $_.PackageFamilyName; $_.taskid | % { $taskid = $_; Set-ItemProperty \"HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\$fname\$taskid\" State 1 -Force } }"`

To run in **BAT**ch/**CMD** file:

`powershell -c "$starts = get-appxpackage -pv app | get-appxpackagemanifest | %% { if ($_.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid) {  [pscustomobject] @{ PackageFamilyName = $app.PackageFamilyName; TaskID = $_.package.Applications.Application.Extensions.extension.startuptask.taskid} } }; $starts | %% { $fname = $_.PackageFamilyName; $_.taskid | %% { $taskid = $_; Set-ItemProperty \"HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\$fname\$taskid\" State 1 -Force } }"`